# How do I use the APP_MULTI package to support multi-selection in my Oracle Form?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Oracle provides the `APP_MULTI` package (found in the `APPCORE` library) to support multi-selection of records in Oracle Forms. What must I do to my form in order to take advantage of this functionality? For example:

- Which triggers must I implement?
- Which `APP_MULTI` methods should I call and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `APP_MULTI` package allows you to add multi-selection functionality to your form. This includes:

- A single record may be selected by merely clicking on it.
- Multiple records may be selected by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and clicking on various records.
- Multiple records may be selected in bulk by choosing "Select All" from the application menu.
- Multiple records may be deselected in bulk by choosing "Deselect All" from the application menu.
- Multiple records may be selected in bulk by clicking the first record, then holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, then clicking the last record.

### Enabling the functionality

The `APP_MULTI` package works by responding to the following events on your form:

- `DESELECT_ALL`
- `KEY-CLRFRM`
- `KEY-CLRREC`
- `KEY-CREREC`
- `KEY-DELREC`
- `POST-BLOCK`
- `PRE-BLOCK`
- `SELECT_ALL`
- `WHEN-CLEAR-BLOCK`
- `WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK`
- `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE`

Unfortunately, the package cannot automatically "hook" into these events. Rather, you are responsible for creating the necessary triggers and explicitly calling the `APP_MULTI.EVENT` procedure in each of them, passing along the name of the event being handled. This procedure is declared as follows:

```
  PROCEDURE event(event_name VARCHAR2,
                  blockname  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

For example, your `KEY-CLRFRM` trigger could be as simple as this:

```
APP_MULTI.EVENT('KEY-CLRFRM');
```

Notice that the procedure accepts an optional `blockname` argument. If `blockname` is `NULL`, the procedure will use the value of `SYSTEM.TRIGGER_BLOCK` instead.

If you want **all** data blocks on your form to receive multi-selection functionality, you can create your triggers on the form rather than on individual data blocks. If you only want certain data blocks to receive the functionality, you can create the triggers on those data blocks *or* you can create a trigger on the form and perform your own check to determine if `APP_MULTI.EVENT` should be called.

### Responding to selection/deselection events

You can be notified of selections and deselections by implementing the custom `MULTI_RETURN_ACTION` trigger (either in your data block or at the top level of your form). This trigger will be fired after **every** selection or deselection of a record (even when records are being selected/deselected in bulk). In your trigger, you may take advantage of these values to better understand the context:

- The `GLOBAL.APPCORE_MULTI_BLOCK` global contains the name of the data block being affected by the selection/deselection.
- The `GLOBAL.APPCORE_MULTI_ACTION` global may be any of the following:

  - `'RECORD_SELECTED'` when a record has been selected
  - `'RECORD_DESELECTED'` when a record has been deselected
  - `'LABEL_CHANGE'` when the "Select All" and "Deselect All" menu items are being enabled or disabled (typically occurs when focus enters or leaves a data block respectively)
- The `APP_MULTI.LOOPING` package variable may be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, depending on whether or not `MULTI_RECORD_ACTION` was called within a loop (that is, if records are being selected/deselected in bulk).

During bulk operations, `APP_MULTI` will call the `MULTI_RETURN_ACTION` trigger once more after all selections/deselections are complete. During this last call, `GLOBAL.APPCORE_MULTI_ACTION` will be set to `'LABEL_CHANGE'` and `APP_MULTI.LOOPING` will be set to `FALSE`. For performance reasons, you may wish to take advantage of this final call to avoid unnecessary calculations during bulk operations. For example, your `MULTI_RETURN_ACTION` could look something like this:

```
IF NOT APP_MULTI.LOOPING THEN
  costly_calculation();
END IF;
```

### Determining which records are currently selected

For each data block, `APP_MULTI` maintains a record group that contains the currently selected record numbers. For a given data block, you may access this record group's only column via the `APP_MULTI.GET_GROUP_COL` function. You can also determine the number of selected records via the `APP_MULTI.GET_GROUP_COUNT` function. Both these functions accept the name of a data block as their only parameter.

For example, suppose you have a data block named `CUSTOMER` with a field named `CUSTOMER_NAME`. You can print out the names of the selected customers via this code:

```
PROCEDURE PRINT_SELECTED_CUSTOMER_NAMES IS
  record_number_column GROUPCOLUMN;
  selected_record_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  record_number_column := APP_MULTI.GET_GROUP_COL('CUSTOMER');
  selected_record_count := APP_MULTI.GET_GROUP_COUNT('CUSTOMER');

  FOR i IN 1 .. selected_record_count LOOP
    DECLARE
      record_number NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      record_number := GET_GROUP_NUMBER_CELL(record_number_column, i);
      GO_RECORD(record_number);
      print(:CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

### Implementation details

For each data block with multi-selection enabled, the `APP_MULTI` package maintains a separate record group whose name is `blockname || '_MULTI'`. This record group contains one row for each selected record. It's only column (`REC_NUM`) stores the record number of the selected record. This is the `GROUPCOLUMN` returned by the `APP_MULTI.GET_GROUP_COLUMN` function mentioned earlier.

For example, suppose you have a data block named `CUSTOMER` and you have selected the 1<sup>st</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup> and 9<sup>th</sup> records. The `CUSTOMER_MULTI` record group will contain this data:

```
+---------+
| REC_NUM |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       4 |
|       9 |
+---------+
```

After deselecting the 4<sup>th</sup> record, the `CUSTOMER_MULTI` record group will now look like this:

```
+---------+
| REC_NUM |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       9 |
+---------+
```

Although you are able to navigate this record group using the standard built-ins (`FIND_GROUP`, `FIND_COLUMN`, `GET_GROUP_ROW_COUNT`), it is preferable to use the `GET_GROUP_COL` and `GET_GROUP_COUNT` functions of the `APP_MULTI` package instead.